# runtime conditional attribute

Tags: c#, code-generation, postsharp

I want to achieve a similar result to that of the .Net framework's ConditionalAtribute except that the condition must be evaluated at runtime. Currently i have wipped up some prototype code (using PostSharp) that somewhat does this with one drawback - it modifies the method body and not the callsite. So in the following example the GetArg() Method is called 2 times, but the desired effect is that it should only be called the first time.

```
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class RuntimeConditionalAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        public abstract bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            if (!Enabled)
                args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;

        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ConditionalTest : RuntimeConditionalAttribute
    {
        public static bool enabled = true;

        public override bool Enabled
        {
            get { return enabled; }
            set { enabled = value; }
        }
    }

    private static string GetArg()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("GetArg()");
        return "";
    }

    [ConditionalTest]
    private static void SayHello(string arg)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Hello, world.");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        ConditionalTest.enabled = true;
        SayHello(GetArg());
        ConditionalTest.enabled = false;
        SayHello(GetArg());
    }
```

Are there other similar compiler tools that i could use to generate what i need? Could i achieve it with PostSharp?

EDIT:Typically what the generated code should do to achieve my result is to wrap the call to the function in an if which tests the conditional first like so:

```
        if(ConditionalTest.enabled) // generated
        {
            SayHello(GetArg());
        }
```

Comment: You could put the ConditionalTest on the GetArg, but I don't see how you could trick the compiler not to call it during runtime with just attributes on the method.

Comment: maybe my edit will clarify what i expect

Comment: that's understandable. I just don't think you can achieve it through PostSharp. You could possibly achieve it by writing something that processes the CIL and modifies it, but is it really worth it?

Comment: _"Eradicate boilerplate. Raise abstraction. Enforce good design."_ I think its worth it. that way its one less piece of code that i can make typos and incorrect/missing logic.

Comment: it doesnt have to be PostSharp, but im looking for anything that will do what i need. (except myself writing the compiler addon code to do this kind of modification)

Comment: I'm just not aware of one that exists.